# pcregrep fails due to segmentation fault

Tags: sed, grep, awk, perl

I am extracting the HTML source of a web page using the below command.

```
curl http://www.linkedin.com/pub/ramesh-venkataraman/63/621/b42 -s |  w3m -dump -T text/html > foo.txt
```

The `foo.txt` has the contents of the web page without any HTML tags. Now, I know in my webpage there is a particular section which always starts with a keyword. For example, after the above command, I run the below command to extract from the substring from that particular value.

```
pcregrep -M 'Skills & Expertise(\n|.)*' foo.txt > foo1.txt
```

The above command works perfectly fine. Now, the problem is when the page becomes very large, I am getting `Segmentation fault` error.

I believe `Segmentation fault` occurs because the grep command tries to do a greedy match and it is failing.

Is there an efficient way to replace the above `pcregrep` command so that I do not get the `Segmentation fault` error?

Comment: You could report the segfault as a bug. Segfaults are always bugs. I am sure the pcregrep maintainers would be happy to get your report. How big is the file in question? Why not use regular grep?

Comment: The file is 365 lines long.

Comment: According to http://www.pcre.org/, the bug tracker is at http://bugs.exim.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=PCRE Go for it. :-)

Comment: Does `grep -P` work instead of `pcregrep`?

Comment: I get the segmentation fault error for grep -P also.

Comment: @Ramesh 365 lines is not "very large". Maybe the problem is with your regex. Are you showing us the whole regex or did you leave some parts out?

Comment: I showed the whole regex. I have posted an answer using awk command. It was working fine for the faulty file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this using `awk` command without getting segmentation fault error.

```
awk 'f;/Skills & Expertise/{f=1}' foo.txt
```

The above command works fine.